# Ошибка "Неверно задано имя папки"

Tags: python, экранирование, файловые-пути

программа в python выдает ошибку "NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] Неверно задано имя папки:C:\Users\Evdokiya\"
Понимаю, что ей не нравятся двойные слэшы, но как от них избавиться?? программу взяла с сайта и там в примере все работает правильно.

пример программы

```
import os

def read_landsat8_b4b5(base_path):
    """Читайте B4,B5 Band
    base_path:  Папка, в которой хранится несколько изображений
    mid_path:  Папка в разных полосах хранится, соответствующая одному изображению
    final_path:  Однополосный файл, который можно открыть непосредственно на последнем уровне
    """

    files_b4 = []
    files_b5 = []
    key_b4 = 'B4.TIF'
    key_b5 = 'B5.TIF'

     # Читать файл внешнего слоя
    base_files = os.listdir(base_path)

     # Прочтите средний файл
    for mid_file in base_files:
        mid_path = base_path + '\\' + mid_file
        mid_files = os.listdir(mid_path)

             # 4 Список файла B4, B5 Band
        for final_file in mid_files:
            final_path = base_path + '\\' + mid_file + '\\' + final_file
            if key_b4 in final_file:
                files_b4.append(final_path)
            if key_b5 in final_file:
                files_b5.append(final_path)

    return files_b4, files_b5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_path = r'E:\ROMOTE_DATA\LANDSAT_202009'
    f_b4, f_b5 = read_landsat8_b4b5(base_path)
    print('B4 Band: {b4}'.format(b4=f_b4))
    print('B5 Band: {b5}'.format(b5=f_b5))
```

нашла в интернете, что можно применить mid_path = os.path.join(base_path, mid_file) но это ничего не поменяло.

Comment: откуда в ошибке взялось "C:\Users\Evdokiya\", если в коде нет ничего, что могло бы обратиться по этому пути?

Comment: это код из примера. в base_path я указала путь до своих файлов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело не в двойных слешах, хотя `os.path.join`, конечно, гораздо лучше! В каталоге `base_path`, вероятно, есть файл, а не только каталоги, а на файле вызов `mid_files = os.listdir(mid_path)` выдает указанную ошибку.

Update: вероятное решение (несформулированной) задачи. пути к файлам из f_b4, f_b5 можно использовать для открытия файлов, или преобразовать в строки, если нужен только список

```
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    base = Path(r'C:\Users\Evdokia')
    f_b4, f_b5 = base.glob('**/*B4.TIF'), base.glob('**/*B5.TIF')
    print(f'B4 Band: {list(f_b4)}')
    print(f'B5 Band: {list(f_b5)}')
```

Comment: Т.е. файлов быть не должно ?
Не подскажите, что нужно тогда сделать, если в каталоге base_path сразу идут файлы ? Тогда не нужны mid_path и final_path ?

Comment: Я как-то в этом запутанном алгорите не очень понимаю задачу. Пострайтесь "словами" написать, что там нужно сделать-то, и какие файлы и каталоги есть у Вас. Можно написать Update в вопросе. Потому что ваши данные, похоже, не совпадают с теми, которые решал приведенный код.  Ну и замечу, если важно, что проверка `if key_b4 in final_file:` зависит от регистра, т.е. файл  `'XYZ_B4.tiff'` её не пройдет.

Comment: у меня есть каталог фалов типа tif (спутниковые снимки) для расчета NDVI мне нужно из всего каталога взять только два файла, у них длинные названия, но в конце обязательное будет B4.TIF и B5.TIF. Далее уже непосредственно работать с данными файлами. Тут в примере почему то очень длинный путь. Мне кажется, что можно сразу указать путь к каталогу со всеми tif и там уже выбрать конкретные 4 и 5

Comment: Ну тогда используйте код в моем дополненном вчера ответе. Там будут списки файлов, если он один, то в списках по одному элементу.

Comment: Подскажите,  print(f'B4 Band: {list(f_b4)}') выдает результат не просто путь до нужно файла, а именно 
"[WindowsPath('C:/Users/Evdokiya/3D Objects/example/LC08_L2SP_169022_20230219_20230223_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF')]"
Можно как-нибудь избавиться от WindowsPath, а то другая часть код с этим не хочет работать. 
Можно сделать так, чтобы просто путь C:/Users/Evdokiya/3D Objects/example/LC08_L2SP_169022_20230219_20230223_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF выдавался ?

Comment: Если уверены, что файл есть, то `str(list(f_b4)[0])`

Comment: Да, учтите, что `f_b4, f_b5` - генераторы, т.е. в список их можно преобразовать один раз, потом уже работать с этим списком.